# Listdefinition: Automatic ordering on date

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

I have my listdefinition up and running but I would like to add something extra. I would like that the content gets sorted automatically by date. This is the column of that listdefinition.

```
<list:column id="DateColumn" type="data" title="{Resources:MyExtension.Strings, Date}" selector="@activitydate"
             translate="Utilities.translateDateNoTime" enablefiltering="true"
             columnfilter="value" />
```

So is there a way to specify that I want my content ordered by date for this column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<list:rows>
    <list:defaultSortField>@activitydate</list:defaultSortField>
</list:rows>
```